# How to display longday event react fullcalendar?

Tags: reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cdekg.png)

`{ title: 'My Long Day Event', start: '2023-05-28', end: '2023-05-30', },`

Im trying to show longday task in react fullcalendar.
When I drag&drop, I can see the range of task properly.
But it didn't work in normal status.

Use official docs code dose not work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.